# Can't extract .tar.xz archive on 13.10 because permission denied

Tags: tar

I used to have Ubuntu 13.04, and also I had installed VLC 2.1.0 with a .tar.xz archive on that, but after the release of 13.10, I removed 13.04 and installed 13.10, so I tried to install VLC 2.1.0 from the normal PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```

...but it installed VLC 2.0.9 for me, so I removed that and tried to install VLC the way I had installed it before on Ubuntu 13.04:

```
wget -c download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/2.1.0/vlc-2.1.0.tar.xz
tar -xJvf download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/2.1.0/vlc-2.1.0.tar.xz
cd vlc-2.1.0
sudo apt-get build-dep vlc
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

...but suddenly an error occurred while extracting the .tar.xz file :
 `Error setting owner : Operation not permitted`, but the owner of file is me and I changed the all the file's permissions in file properties to read and write, but it doesn't work, so what can I do?

And also if it doesn't work, suggest a good way to install VLC 2.1.0!

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and VLC 2.1.0. I tried:
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install vlc

Comment: Do you have permission on the directory? Parent and subs?

Comment: yes ,the file is directly in my home folder ! and also that ppa installs 2.0.9 for me !

Comment: What's the output of `ls -al`?

Comment: @guntbert that bug is for file-roller, `tar` should be unaffected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tar file seems to have problems, I couldn't figure out why I had to do it in two steps:

1. I used `xz` to decompress the file:

   ```
   xz -d vlc-2.1.0.tar.xz
   ```
2. Now I used tar to unpack the tar file:

   ```
   tar xf vlc-2.1.0.tar
   ```
3. I can `cd` to the directory now:

   ```
   cd vlc-2.1.0
   ```

In a nutshell:

```
wget -c download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/2.1.0/vlc-2.1.0.tar.xz
xz -d vlc-2.1.0.tar.xz
tar xf vlc-2.1.0.tar
cd vlc-2.1.0
```

---

I redownloaded the file and surprise, it worked. Extracting the file with `tar Jxf vlc-2.1.0.tar.xz` was all I had to do. If for any motive it doesn't work, redownload it.

Comment: I had no problems with the file: `tar xf vlc-2.1.0.tar.xz` just worked flawlessly...

Comment: Mm... apparently just now I tried, and it worked. But I swear just now it didn't!